# Why the value of i is not changing inside the for loop

Tags: java

```
class Test 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
     {
         int i=1;
         for(int j=0;j<=2;j++)
             {
                 i=i++;
             }
          System.out.println(i);
      }
}
```

Why in this question the value of i is printing 1.

Comment: Change the line from `i=i++` to `i++`.

Answer (score 2):

`i=i++;` doesn't change i.
It increments i but then assigns the old value of i to i (since the post increment operator returns the old value of the incremented number).

Either write :

`i++;`

or

`i=i+1;`